# undefined control sequence \OT when ß appears in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, accents, tocloft, bugs

I use the command `\addtocontents`

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{Laßt, ihr buntbemützten Scharen}\vspace*{2.5pt}

}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

which writes the following gibberish to the toc

```
\textbf {La\OT 1\ss t, ihr buntbem\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {u\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 127 u\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor tzten Scharen\unhbox \voidb@x \hbox {}}\vspace *{2.5pt} \par
```

The `\OT 1` causes an error. If I remove it, I get the desired output. The question is: How can I remove it? I suspect, it is inserted by a bug, which means, I need a workaround. I can not replace ß by `\ss`, since `Laßt, ihr.....` itself is a result in an edef.

Is this a known bug/error. I couldn't find any similar problems.

I suspect helvet, tocloft, scrpage2 and scrbook as the "bad guys". Commenting them out is either impossible (because essential) or causes other errors, but no solution.

Comment: `tocloft` and `scrbook`  together? Really? ... and no, they are not the bad guys. Also `scrpage2` is obsolete. I don't get the error you report with TL2017 on Linux

Comment: Did you try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know, that koma provides afaik the stuff to edit the toc. But getting into that koma stuff took me too long, so I put it back. I probably will take care of this later.

Comment: @Bernard Just tried it. This replaces the ucs-error by another one. This time `\T1`.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: I don't use KOMA any longer for years now;  replacing `scrbook` with `book` etc. does not cause the error you report. Remove any `.aux` etc. file and recompile

Comment: @ChristianHupfer May I ask, why you dont use `scrbook` anymore?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: Personal distaste. I know, this is blasphemy in German LaTeX community and I will get a lot of criticism for my opinion ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Nope. Still causes problems. I use pdflatex.

Comment: with texlive 2017 I get no error and a toc of `\select@language {ngerman}
\textbf {La\IeC {\ss }t, ihr buntbem\IeC {\"u}tzten Scharen}\vspace *{2.5pt} \par `

Comment: out of curiosity i tried this with pdflatex (tex live 2016).  the error message is even more weird:
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \GenericError {(inputenc)               
 }{Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ßt (U+93)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX}...`
what's that "ßt"?  the "t" shouldn't be there at all.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think to get that you have to save the file in latin1? (while leaving inputenc declared as utf8)

Comment: you haven't said what tex system you use (as I say it works in a current system) presumably a workaround is to use `\ss ` instead of  `ß`

Comment: post the log file that you get from the above, you must have some old files in your input path I would guess

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: `pdflatex` is pretty obvious, I think.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz I tried your very example with TeX Live from 2012 to 2017 and never get the weird output.

Comment: Complete reinstalling of MikTeX could not solve the problem.

Comment: please do as requested previously and post the log that yiu get from the above. Most likely reinstalling miktex did not help as you are using some old local files that are masking the correct definitions.

Comment: With current MiKTeX I get no error or warning ...  Please add the log file to your question ...

Comment: Please fix the wording of this question which is currently completely false. The posted example does **not** "which writes the following gibberish to the toc"  The posted example works without error and some unshown code writes that to the toc.

Answer (score 1):

Imho your example doesn't tell the truth. You are probably having an \edef involved. Something like this would give your output and your error (after the second compilation):

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\begin{document}
\edef\test{Laßt, ihr buntbemützten Scharen}

\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{\test}\vspace*{2.5pt}}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

If your real code contains such an \edef: Use `\protected@edef` instead. This here would work in my example (delete the old toc first):

```
\makeatletter
\protected@edef\test{Laßt, ihr buntbemützten Scharen}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Correct, I used an edef. But I mentioned it also. It is part of a sty-file with 400 lines (which will increase - this is going to be the Liederbuch-package). So it is sometimes a bit tricky to build MWEs. Sorry. But, what I haven't understood, is: What does `\protected@edef` actually do? Because there is no `\protected` in front of `ß` / `\ss`.

Comment: I will do some tests and report.

Comment: You mentioned the \edef only in a side remark. From the comments you can see that everyone thought your example demonstrates the error and tried to figure out why and you did nothing to correct this impression. This is unfriendly and also dumb: if you had made clear that the example is lying David and egreg would have guessed directly that you have an unprotected \edef or \write somewhere. Regarding the `\protected@edef`: ß has a rather clever definition which prevents the break unless you force it to break by using `\edef` when you shouldn't (which is almost never).

Comment: @MaestroGlanz it is completely unhelpful to post an "example" that does not demonstrate the problem in the question, it just wastes everyone's time. `\edef` simply is not a supported command to use on input containing latex commands.

Answer (score 0):

In my problem `ß` changed to `\OT 1\ss`, which expanded to `<ucs-error> 1\ss` expanded to `1ß` instead of `ß`.

I couldn't solve the main problem, but just in case, someone stumbles across this problem:

```
\def\OT#11{} % for understanding: \OT{#1}1 => {}
```

is a workaround. The principle is simple:

```
\OT 1 is defined with #1 = SPACE and 1 = delimiter
```

it expands to nothing.

Comment: You should better show your log-file so that someone can identify the real cause. You shouldn't get an ucs-error unless you madly mistreated your tex system.

Comment: Your explanation of functioning is wrong, `\OT 1` will get `#1` empty not a space. (with the definition above) (the space wll get swallowed by control sequence tokenization)

Comment: This is not an answer to any problem in the test file in the question. If the test file shown produces the error shown then the latex installation  is broken somewhere and defining `\OT` is not going to fix that at all.